# Design nested resources and individual resources actions coexisted for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user case in which nested resources and individual resources both make sense. How can I design path and code structure to reflect this? For example:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end

resources :ads
```

Each `ad` belongs to a `magazine`, so `magazines/:magazine_id/ads` absolutely make sense. However, in some cases, I want to list all `ads` only, so `ads` also make sense. Please note, `magazines/:magazine_id/ads` and `ads` have completely different `view`. The same thing applies to other actions. Does anyone have similar situation? And what is the better way to solve it and structure code in `mvc`?

Comment: This sounds like a simple _filter by magazine_ to me.

Comment: @spickermann, but the view and action are completely different. So I cannot just simply filter it.

Comment: Can you provide examples how the actions and the views will differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes should be fine, you can handle the difference in a controller - there will be difference in params: `:magazine_id` will be present or absent.

If you want to separate the controllers completely, you can use `module:` in your routes:

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads, module: 'nested'
end
resources :ads
```

The first one would point to `Nested::AdsController`, the second to `AdsController`

Or the other way around

```
resources :magazines do
  resources :ads
end
resources :ads, module: 'unnested'
```

First one points to `AdsController`, second to `Unnested::AdsController`.